# Why Chrome Canary Always Open Chrome Stable? (os x)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-mountain-lion

Always when I open canary, it opens chrome stable!! I can't have canary running without chrome stable opened. If I quit chrome stable, the canary keeps opening it!! It's annoying.

I could't figure out what is the setting to disable that.

It's normal? How can I disable this?

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! The problem is with rescue time. If I disable it, the problem don't happens.

[This bug have been reported some time ago](http://help.rescuetime.com/kb/rescuetime-installable-client/odd-behavior-with-chrome-canary-when-rescuetime-is-running)

Comment: wow, thanks for this - I threw a hissy fit rack my brains as to why Chrome was possessed. funny how they still haven't fixed it